# Events not being tracked in AppCenter for WPF (.Net Core)

Tags: wpf, .net-core

I can see custom events flowing in Analytics -> Log flow almost real-time, but Analytics -> Events is not showing anything. Is there a delay, or am I doing something wrong?

My startup setup:

```
using Microsoft.AppCenter;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;

...

var countryCode = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.TwoLetterISORegionName;
AppCenter.SetCountryCode(countryCode);
AppCenter.SetUserId($"{Environment.UserName}@{Environment.MachineName}");
AppCenter.Start("xxx", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```

then to track an event:
`Analytics.TrackEvent($"Test");`

This is WPF .Net Core 3.1 app. SDK version is 3.4.3

Comment: Are you running it on a Windows OS?

Comment: In your real code for the .Start. Instead of "xxx" you have a valid app secret?

Comment: @Ehssan Yes, Windows, it's a WPF application.

Comment: @Andy Yes, app secret is valid. Crashes and log flows are coming through just fine.

Comment: The Events page says "Check out the Log Flow to see if the events are correctly tracked. After a few minutes they will appear in detail here." I take that there is a few minutes delay, but it should not take hours for an Event to show?

Comment: Also something I noted is that log timestamp is an hour behind. I triggered event in an app at 12:28:53 and log flow is showing 11:28:53

Comment: You've set your correct country code? That looks like a timezone difference.

Comment: @Andy Yes, ```var countryCode = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.TwoLetterISORegionName;``` is correctly evaluating. Analytics Overview is also correctly plotting the map. Crashes show correct time.

Comment: Ha, Events started to coming through! It took them 4 hours, but they are coming retrospectively right now.

Comment: There's supposed to be some cacheing built in and you do often see a delay. That seems way longer than I recall though.